# attributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'TIMEOUT', after ! pip install --upgrade firebase-admin do you know why?

Tags: python, firebase, jupyter-notebook, timeout, pexpect

I'm trying to link firebase cloud to Jupiter notebook and this error keeps popping up.
this error doesn't come when I'm working on google Collab notebook, but I need to use the Jupiter notebook.

! pip install --upgrade firebase-admin